# String comparison in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am wondering about the performance of the following string comparison in where clause:

**Case 1:**

```
MATCH (p: Person)
WHERE NOT p.name='Person 1'
AND NOT p.name='Person 2'
RETURN p
```

**Case 2:**

```
MATCH (p: Person)
WHERE NOT (p.name='Person 1' OR p.name='Person 2')
RETURN p
```

**Case 3:**

```
MATCH (p: Person)
WHERE NOT p.name IN ['Person 1', 'Person 2']
RETURN p
```

I have tried on my database but the result is not united, sometimes case 3 gets be best response time and db hits, sometimes the best is case 1 and case 2.

Can you please make this clear for me?
- Which method has the best performance?
- Why is it the best (maybe the algorithm/logic behind)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 3 should always produce the fewest DB hits. If you `PROFILE` each query, they all generally produce the same execution plan but if you peer into the details in the `Filter` operation you can see the difference.

[image: Case 1 & 2 Profile]

In case 1 & 2 the filter comparison is `not p.name = $` AUTOSTRING0`.

If you look at the profile for Case 3, however, it has a different comparison.

[image]

In case 3 the filter comparison is `not p.name IN $` AUTOLIST0`.

One can infer that Case 1 and 2 treats each new term as a separate *string* comparison but Case 3 performs a *list* comparison. If you scale up the lst of Person anmes the DB hits in Case 3 will remain constant but Case 1 and 2 will scale up linearly.

As your DB grows though this query will never be a *"great performer"* though as it literally does a full table scan on a particular label and filters out the things it doesn't want.

As far as response time goes, the first time you run one of these queries the results are in the page cache so subsequent queries will always be faster. Likewise, once each query has been executed the query plans will  cached, so it is just going to vary a little when you compare them.

Comment: Thank you a lot, Dave,
But in case I have to create a filter like that and the number of unique values of the desired property is very low, so what is the best strategy?
Indexing will not make sense because the property is not so selective.